# Download PDF and Attach It To an Email

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

Here is my issue, I generated a web page (external web page that does not belong to my existing project) that produces a PDF file that is being saved on the server in a temp folder. The PDF will be generated with given parameters.
I want to save whatever that webpage produces (PDF) and attach it to an email so the result will be ----> Attaching PDF to an email.

```html
Dim FullReportUrl As String = Nothing
            FullReportUrl = (String.Format("https://www.something.com/Reports/ReportManager.aspx?SessionID={0}&report=CaseFullReport&CompanyCode={1}&ExportType=pdf&ConnectionType=Main&GlobalVar=IncidentID^{2}|CompanyCode^{3}", "2c3fe87f-5c4e-4a7d-acda-970ed47f27eb", m_User.CompanyCode, m_IncidentCaseID.ToString(), m_User.CompanyCode))

            '# Create mail message
            Dim msg As New MailMessage
            msg.From = New MailAddress(Globals.gFromEmailAddr)
            msg.To.Add(New MailAddress("test@something.com"))
            msg.Subject = String.Concat("Full Report IR-", m_IncidentID.ToString())
            '# Attach the additional text to the E-Mail.
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(rtbAdditionalText.Text.ToString()) Then
                msg.Body = "<html><body>Dear " + "Test" + ",  (Please Do Not Replay to this email)<br><br>" + rtbAdditionalText.Text.ToString().Trim() + "<br><br> Sincerely,<br> Something." + "<br><img id=""Logo"" alt=""logo"" src=""https://www.something.com/gs/Images/Layout/logo.png""/></body></html>"
            End If

            msg.IsBodyHtml = True
            msg.Priority = MailPriority.High


            '# Attach the full report to the email.

            Dim ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream
            Dim writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(ms)
            With writer
                .Write(GetFileStream(FullReportUrl))
                .Flush()

                'ms.Position = 0 '== Reading the stream from the beginging and finializing it.
                Dim attach As Attachment = New Attachment(ms, "test.pdf", System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf)
                msg.Attachments.Add(attach)
            End With

          

            'Create client and send
            Dim client As New SmtpClient(Globals.gMailServer)
            client.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("test@something.com", "555555$")

            Dim userState As Object = msg
            client.Send(msg)
            msg = Nothing
            client.Dispose()
```

The PDF coming out corrupted. Can someone point out why?

Comment: Your posted code is VB.NET, yet you tagged your question with both C# and VB.NET.  Which one do you want? What do you do with `FullReportUrl`?  Is the Report URL what returns the PDF?

Comment: FullReportURL - URL that produce a PDF file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the data of the PDF in a

```
byte[]
```

with a

```
StreamReader
```

over an

```
HttpWebRequest
```

with  the URL that generate you PDF file
,then it'll be easier to attach it to an email

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear to me if you have control over the server.  If so I would create an api which give you a file stream result.   Pseudo code below (sorry for the c#)
    public FileStreamResult Index(int id)

```
    {
        MemoryStream mystream = new MemoryStream(); 
        mystream = {Generate pdf code}
        return new FileStreamResult(mystream,"application/pdf");
    }
```

Your client would look something like this

```
public Sub GetPDFfromAPI(int id)
       dim myfile as byte() = Nothing
        dim handler as HttpClientHandler  = new HttpClientHandler()
        dim myclient as new HttpClient(handler)
        dim client as new 
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://myhosturl")
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear()
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/octet-stream"))

            Dim response as HttpResponseMessage  = client.Get("api/ControllerName/"+id.ToString())
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) then


                 myfile = response.Content.ReadAsByteArray()


            else

                return null
            End if
    Dim oFileStream As System.IO.FileStream
    oFileStream = New System.IO.FileStream("myfile.pdf",System.IO.FileMode.Create)
    oFileStream.Write(myfile, 0, myfle.Length)
    oFileStream.Close()
```

Its probably a good practice to make the methods async

Comment: I'll try to be more clear about my question: By calling the webpage it produce back a PDF. I want to grab that PDF and attach it to an email. So basically in the code behind I don't want to display the PDF on that webpage, I want to download it push it to an email as an attachment. See the code that I posted.